# How can I find total size of file in bytes?

Tags: linux, shell, perl, size, filesize

I want total of file size in bytes. This is my code.

```
my $total= print `stat --printf="%s\n" www/ | du -ah www/* > report.txt `;
```

I got output in K. But I want in Byte so how can I get and how can I find total?

My out is coming like this

```
4.0K www/1.html
3.0K www/2.html
```

Comment: [stat](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) or [-s](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) to get the size of a file in perl.

Comment: you can use `du` command with the **b** flag.

Comment: @Shawn but I also write my output

Comment: @MiguelÁngelRetamozoSanchez but how can I find total for that?

Comment: @Jack so what? Do you not know how to write data to a file in perl (do you even need to do such a thing?) Maybe you should be doing whatever this is in a shell script instead if you don't...

Comment: Why are you piping the output of `stat` to `du` in that snippet anyways? You're also giving `du` a path on it's command line and I don't think it reads from standard input, but if it does, what's it supposed to do with `stat`'s output? It's really strange usage.

Comment: to sum all and show in bytes  `du -b  <file_with_regex> | awk ' {sum += $1} END {print sum}'`

Comment: @Shawn Yes you right. I just remove that things.

Comment: @MiguelÁngelRetamozoSanchez also u can find total with `du -ach www/`

Comment: `stat` is giving you the size of the directory itself, not the amount of space used by the files listed in it. (compare `ls -ld www/` with `du -sb www/`)

Comment: It's not portable, but for linux (with GNU coreutils or busybox, possibly others), `du` has a `-c` option: `du -cb GLOB`

Answer (score 1):

First you do not give enough information to help.

Then you ask for the total size in your headline but then show som shell code and ask how to get the size in bytes for the du command.

Seems you didn't understand `du` but simply copied it from somewhere. `du -h` is for "human readable" output, which you would have known had you read `man du`.

And then you try to put output from shell commands into a perl variable. You will only get the value 1 btw.

If you really want to go for perl, try to understand what (as an example)

```
while (<www/*>) …
```

will do. Also check `perldoc -f -X`. Search for `-s`.

The total size you can get by summing up the individual sizes collected with `-s`. Ah! And there is also a `stat` in perl. Check `perldoc -f stat`.

I  hope this is enough to get you going…